# Object Oriented Programming with python issue with the list?

Tags: python

Code is not printing the multiple elements that I add to it. Instead it is just printing out the recently added element. can anyone guide me on this?

```
class bikes:
    def __init__(self,make,name,model):
        self.make = make
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        self.all_bikes = []
    def total_bikes(self):
        self.counter = 0
        dict_bikes = {"Make": self.make,
                       "Name": self.name,
                       "Model": self.model}
        self.all_bikes.append({self.counter : dict_bikes})
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
    def show_all_bikes(self):
        print(self.all_bikes)

class user(bikes):
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_make = make = input("Enter the Company name: ")
        self.user_name = name = input("Enter the Bike name: ")
        self.user_model = model = input("Enter the Model name: ")
        super().__init__(make,name,model)
        bikes.total_bikes(self)
while True:
    menu = input("Enter Add,View to Add a new bike and View all bikes: ")
    if menu.upper() == "ADD":
        add_bike = user()
    elif menu.upper() == "VIEW":
        add_bike.show_all_bikes()
    else:
        print("Invalid Command")
```

Comment: Could you fix your formatting please?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Is a user actually a type of bike? Can a user have more than one bike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This construct

```
while True:
    menu = input("Enter Add,View to Add a new bike and View all bikes: ")
    if menu.upper() == "ADD":
        add_bike = user()
    elif menu.upper() == "VIEW":
        add_bike.show_all_bikes()
    else:
        print("Invalid Command")
```

if `ADD` is choice then new instance of `user` class is created, which has empty `all_bikes`. You need to equip your class with seperate method for adding bike and `__init__` and createdinstance of `user` class before entering `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please write the code here. That would be really helpful. Thank you.